# Asmack fileReceiving fail

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, asmack

I am using asmack 16 library. I am able to send files. but I am not able to receive. when I try send file from desktop client(pidgin) to my android client, I am getting log that FileNegotiation 0.0. and some percentage like 20% or 10% showing on desktop client...

Code:

```html
public void ReceiveFile(XMPPConnection con) {
  Log.i("ADITYA", "IN ReceiveFile");
  if(con != null){
   Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void run() {
     /*ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
       .getInstanceFor(m_connection);
     if (sdm == null)*/
     sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(m_connection);

     ProviderManager pm = ProviderManager.getInstance();
     pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("active", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("composing", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("paused", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("gone", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
     pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup", "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses", "http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());
     pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
     pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());


     sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"); 
     sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#item");
     sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");


     // Create the file transfer manager
     final FileTransferManager managerListner = new FileTransferManager(
       m_connection);

     FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(m_connection, true);
     FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true;

     Log.i("File transfere manager", "created");

     // Create the listener
     managerListner
     .addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
      public void fileTransferRequest(
        final FileTransferRequest request) {

       Log.i("Recieve File",
         "new file transfere request  new file transfere request   new file transfere request");

       Log.i("file request",
         "from" + request.getRequestor());

       Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "accepted");
       IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
       try {

        Log.i("ADITYA", "IN Try");
        transfer.recieveFile(new File(mImagePath+request.getFileName()));

        while (!transfer.isDone()) {

         Log.i("ADITYA", "IN while");
         Thread.sleep(2000L);
         Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "still receiving : "
           + (transfer.getProgress()) + " status "
           + transfer.getStatus());

         if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
          // Log.i("Error file",
          // transfer.getError().getMessage());
          Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog",
            "cancelling still receiving : "
              + (transfer.getProgress())
              + " status "
              + transfer.getStatus());
          System.out.println("While Receiveing file");
          System.out.println("Error transfer.getError() : "+transfer.getError());
          System.out.println("transfer.getException() : "+transfer.getException());
          transfer.cancel();

          break;
         }
        }
        
        if(transfer.isDone()){
         System.out.println("ADITYA"+transfer.getStatus());
         System.out.println("ADITYA :: DONE");
        }else{
         System.out.println("transfer.getException() : "+transfer.getStatus());
         System.out.println("ADITYA :: UNDONE");
        }

       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     });
    }
   };
   thread.start();
  }else{
   System.out.println("m_connection is NULL");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Could you post the log as well?

Comment: Which xmpp server are you using??

Comment: File sending from one xmpp client is dependent on two factors. 1 your xmpp client should support file sending.. Here with aSmack socket5 proxy. And your xmpp server should have file sharing module enabled

Comment: Thank you for reply Paul and Dev. After researches i found solution so, now able to send and receive files.. New topic is that  getting offline messages..

Comment: @AdityaMalladi can you help in solving this problem. I used this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/btreu6TYtDK3iKjeFEg5BT) but not able to receive even this log Log.i("InstallerActivity", "Got new File!!!");

Comment: @nawab saab need some more inputs. Which library(version) you are using?

Comment: @AdityaMalladi there? and I am using asmack-android-6 jar

Comment: @AdityaMalladi if you can give only 5 mins from your busy schedule in helping me to solve this issue, then please come over this [link.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn-android) Thanks